# Graphdb Startup failure after computer reboot

Tags: graphdb

I had to shutdown graphdb due to a reboot but now after starting up again I get a long list of errors...

[Error message here as it is too long for stackoverflow](https://gist.github.com/jjkoehorst/2975f033f39c40800197031f4f5acaa7)

I am now running the storage tool to export the few dozen graphs I have in there but is there a way to restore and startup graphdb again? It is version 8.0.2 and I am planning to upgrade it soon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All GraphDB errors with messages like the one below indicate that the Workbench failed to deserialize the internal database containing information about the currently active location, users, permissions, saved SPARQL queries, application states like diagrams, etc.

```
[ERROR] 2017-06-23 07:51:55,256 [localhost-startStop-1 | o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener|
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileTasksExecutor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryActionClassHierarchyListener' defined in URL [jar:file:/ssd/graphdb-free-8.0.2/lib/workbench/WEB-INF/lib/graphdb-framework-graph-explore-8.0.2.jar!/com/ontotext/forest/graphexplore/listener/RepositoryActionClassHierarchyListener.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.ontotext.forest.graphexplore.service.ClassHierachyStorageService]: : Error creating bean with name 'classHierachyStorageService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'classHierachyStorageService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception i|
s java.lang.NullPointerException
```

To reinitialize the Workbench's meta-data rename or delete the directory `{$gdb.home.work}`. This operation will remove all Workbench specific configurations only and keep all your repository data!